# ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR when connecting to Cloud SQL using Cloud SQL Proxy on localhost

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql, cloud-sql-proxy

When I try running an npm init script on terminal to create a SQL table on Cloud SQL using a Cloud SQL Proxy on my localhost I get a:

> ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR

I can connect using Sequel pro but get that error connecting from terminal, would appreciate the help.